# User not able to see the task report which assigned to others

Tags: reporting, tasks

One of my user created report on Task(All Open & Completed). User not able to see the tasks in the report which he created and assigned to others. User can only see which is assigned to him. My User want to see the tasks which is assigned to others also. How can get this all tasks in the report.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your OWD sharing model is private, users can't see tasks which are not assigned to them.

And yet, you can change that by setting the OWD on the Activity to 'Controlled-By-Parent' and then set the parent object (Account/Case/Lead) setting to 'Public Read/Write'. Note that changing the sharing setting to Public is not recommended.